# Calculating Changes in Velocity

Tags: velocity

When $+6.0$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$ becomes $+15$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$ is it said to have a change in velocity of $9$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$.

If so, when a direct velocity such as $+6.0$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$ changes to $-15$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$ is it's change in velocity $21$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$ or $-21$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

When calculating any change, the proper order is new - old:
$$\Delta S = S_\text{new}-S_\text{old} \text{ or } S_\text{final}-S_\text{initial}.$$

$S$ represents any scaler or vector quantity.

Comment: One might add that this is only a convention. If you do it consistently, the other way around, everything will work out fine (but people reading your calculation will be pretty baffled).